# hibernate no identifier specified error on playframework

Tags: java, hibernate, playframework

I have inherited a Playframework application with hibernate and with no documentation.

I can get the app to run on my local machine ok and attach eclipse to debug.

However, when I deploy to a linux vm using

```
sbt dist
```

and

```
<my app> -Dplay.http.secret.key=[secret key]
```

I get the following error:

```
Error injecting constructor, org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: dao.LinkedAccountHome
```

I have already searched the various solutions on SO and beyond regarding making sure the entity has an @Id.

The LinkedAccountHome class referenced in the error looks like it has been generated by Hibernate Tools with this message:

```
 * Home object for domain model class LinkedAccount.
 * @see models.LinkedAccount
 * @author Hibernate Tools
```

The LinkedAccount entity it references does indeed have an @Id set:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
public Integer getId() {
    return this.id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}
```

I have tried regenerating the hibernate.cfg.xml and the mapping file, but still get the same error.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Many thanks

Comment: Is the "@Id" correct one? Try to directly import the `javax.persistence.Id`.

Comment: @AndriyKuba, yes the "@Id" is the correct one and both classes import 
    javax.persistence.Id

Comment: It looks like the code is correct, especially if you can "get the app to run on my local machine" so you can actually see that the code that use `LinkedAccountHome` works locally. The next thing - `sbt dist` - check if all the classes and resources are packed correctly and present in the deployment.